# Maximum likelihood for Markov chain with missing observations

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, hidden-markov-models

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be the path of a Markov chain with 3 possible states $\{1,2,3\}$. Given the path, I know how to get the maximum likelihood estimator for the $3 \times 3$ transition probability matrix $P$.

However, I am missing some values of the chain. For example, I have $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^5$ and $\{X_i\}_{i=11}^{15}$ but am missing $\{X_i\}_{i=6}^{10}$. Given an initial probability distribution $p$, the likelihood function for this problem would look like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{\theta}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_5, X_{11}, ..., X_{15}) & = \sum_{X_i, i \in\{6,7,...,10\}} p_{X_1} \prod_{i=2}^{15} P_{X_{i-1}, X_i}\\
& = \sum_{X_6=1}^{3} \sum_{X_7=1}^{3} ... \sum_{X_{10}=1}^{3} \left[ p_{X_1} \prod_{i=2}^{15} P_{X_{i-1}, X_i} \right]
\end{align*}
$$

How should I go about solving for the maximum likelihood estimator for $P$ in this case?